# Tildes en API Google Maps android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy utilizando en una aplicación la API de Google Maps. Utilizo el autocompletar de Google y las calles me salen con tildes, pero cuando las paso a la url para obtener la distancia no me devuelve nada.

Este es el código:

```
str= "Calle Doctor José Montilla Bono, Jaén";
str2= "Gran Via, Calle Gran Vía de Colón, Granada";

String urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + str + "&destinations=" + str2 + "&mode=driving&key=0000000000000000000";
```

Genera la url de consulta: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=CalleDoctorJoséMontillaBono,Jaén&destinations=GranVia,CalleGranVíadeColón,Granada&mode=driving&traffic_model=optimistic&key=0000000000](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=CalleDoctorJos%C3%A9MontillaBono,Ja%C3%A9n&destinations=GranVia,CalleGranV%C3%ADadeCol%C3%B3n,Granada&mode=driving&traffic_model=optimistic&key=0000000000)

pero la aplicación me da fallo y si abro esa url obtengo esto:

> {
>       "destination_addresses" : [],
>       "origin_addresses" : [],
>       "rows" : [],
>       "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
>   }

¿Alguien sabe por que puede ser?

Muchas gracias
Un saludo

Comment: agrega los parametros arrival_time y  departure_time. Además en producción necesitas una API Key valida.

Answer (score 0):

Las tildes en realidad no provocan el problema, el error en realidad esta especificado en la respuesta, es un "invalid request" porque falta el parámetro `departure_time` :

> { destination_addresses: [ ],
>   error_message: "Invalid request. Missing the 'departure_time' parameter.", 
>   origin_addresses: [ ],
>   rows: [ ],
>   status: "INVALID_REQUEST" }

Recuerda que :

> **El parametro `arrival_time` (La hora de llegada) o el parámetro  `departure_time` se debe especificar en cualquier momento en que 
>   solicite direcciones de tránsito.**

Por ejemplo si agregamos los parametros a tu url original, tenemos:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=CalleDoctorJos%C3%A9MontillaBono,Ja%C3%A9n&destinations=GranVia,CalleGranV%C3%ADadeCol%C3%B3n,Granada&mode=driving&traffic_model=optimistic&departure_time=10&arrival_time=12

la respuesta:

```
{
destination_addresses: [
"Calle Gran Vía de Colón, Granada, España"
],
origin_addresses: [
"Calle Dr. José Montilla Bono, 23009 Jaén, España"
],
rows: [
{
elements: [
{
distance: {
text: "92,4 km",
value: 92432
},
duration: {
text: "1h 1 min",
value: 3645
},
status: "OK"
}
]
}
],
status: "OK"
}
```

**Es muy importante que obtengas una API KEY valida, ya que la que usas (`key=0000000000`)no es valida para usar en producción.**